# Trello hash links between cards no longer work?

Tags: trello, trello-cards

I have been building a large board in Trello with extensive use of internal links between cards. I used the #[card number] format for my links, which worked very well. Now the # links no longer work. I can't find any reference to this on the Trello help site. I'm using Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit) on a Macbook Air OS X 10.10.3. I tried Firefox also but same problem. Any help appreciated!

Comment: I know Trello addef support for card commentaar linking as well. Try using the card URL when linking to another card

Comment: Thanks @strages. Yes, only card URL links are supported now. Trello Support responded very quickly and helpfully to advise this. To help speed the most time-consuming part of converting each #[card number] link to the URL for the card (locating each card by its number!), I've found a bookmarklet that enables Trello card number display to be toggled on and off: https://github.com/melior88/showTrelloCardNumbers